# Keep only 10 records per user

Tags: php, mysql

I run points system on my site so I need to keep logs of different action of my users into database. The problem is that I have too many users and keeping all the records permanently may cause server overload... I there a way to keep only 10 records per user and automatically delete older entries? Does mysql have some function for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that it is overloading? What are the symptoms? You should gather some statistics around this before deciding on a solution.

Comment: I am curious, how many users roughly do you have?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a trigger that takes care of removing old entries.
For instance,

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE definer='root'@'localhost' TRIGGER afterMytableInsert AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id ORDER BY action_time DESC LIMIT 10);
END//
```

Comment: I've got MySQL 5.7.14 and cannot create such a trigger - I receive the following error: `Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: OK, to avoid this limitation inside the trigger I can make a statement like `DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id ORDER BY action_time DESC LIMIT 10) foo);` but  then I'm not able to INSERT records into my `MyTable`, I get this response `Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'MyTable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: @sbrbot :  Then probably the easiest way is to use some sort of scheduler, either built-in (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) or external like cron.  I'd also suggest creating a new question since Mysql has evolved quite a while between 8 years ago and now.

Answer (score 2):

Just run an hourly cron job that deletes the 11th - n records.

Comment: My company does this with great success on a 4+million record file.

Answer (score 2):

Before insert a record you could check how many the user has first. If they have >=10 delete the oldest one. Then insert the new one.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have the database ensure that for a given table there are never more than N rows per a given subkey (user) then the correct way to solve this will be either:

- Use [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-views.html) to manage inserts in the table.
- Use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) to delete older rows after an insert.

If you're already using stored procedures for data access, then modifying the insert procedure would make the most sense, otherwise a trigger will be the easiest solution.

Alternately if your goal is to periodically remove old data, then using a cron job to start a stored procedure to prune old data would make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 10 ID FROM Table WHERE USER_ID = 1) AND USER_ID = 1
```

Clearer Version

```
DELETE FROM Table
    WHERE ID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT TOP 10 ID  FROM Table WHERE USER_ID = 1
    )
    AND USER_ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting a new record for a user. Just do a query like this before (Don't forget the `where`-condition):

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE userID = 'currentUserId' LIMIT 9, 999999
```

After that you can insert new data. This keeps the data always to ten records for each user.

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(....)
```